# Why i got unknown error on android studio import

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build, yolo

So i did an android + Yolo5 for object detection. I already got the tflite model and i follow the tutorial from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROn1_O2zEtk . I downloaded the project from github and ready to import with Android Studio. After i import the project, the directory shows black font for files like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B00Ni.png)

The notification also shows this when i tried to build the app :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, D:\Code\YOLOv5\yolov5\android\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@4d320bac) before task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

BUILD FAILED in 688ms
9 actionable tasks: 9 up-to-date
```

I already know the black font means 'unknown' based on this configuration : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSAid.png)

What can i do to solve this problem?